# CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <option> elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is there a way to style the currently selected `<option>` element in a `<select>` element?

I could then give a background color to the currently selected option element? That way I can style the option that's currently viewable in the closed dropdown.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

> the `:checked` pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 `selected` and `checked` attributes

Source: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked)

---

So, this CSS works, although styling the `color` is not possible in every browser:

```
option:checked { color: red; }
```

---

An example of this in action, hiding the currently selected item from the drop down list.

```css
option:checked { display:none; }
```

```html
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

---

To style the currently selected option in the *closed* dropdown as well, you could try reversing the logic:

```
select { color: red; }
option:not(:checked) { color: black; } /* or whatever your default style is */
```

Comment: Did you test it?  It [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/UUznB/) for me on FF8.  *update:* it doesn't work in Chromium 15 either.

Comment: @emmett I too checked it in Chrome 16. As I said in my previous comment it styles the selected option in the dropdown list, but not the one in the closed viewable area.

Comment: @Web_Designer Ok, I see the issue. I edited my answer with another (wonky) solution.

Comment: accepted answer doesn't work for me in chrome. you can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/hk4s0ech/

Answer (score 23):

Actually you can only style few CSS properties on *:modified* option elements.
`color` does not work, `background-color` either, but you can set a `background-image`.

You can couple this with gradients to do the trick.

```css
option:hover,
option:focus,
option:active,
option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(#5A2569, #5A2569);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Works on gecko/webkit.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but this solution did.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that you can also apply filter to it like this:
Option:checked{filter:grayscale(1);}
This is similar to how nowadays you can style checkboxes and radiobuttons in Chrome to make them non-blue.

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me :

```css
select option {
  color: black;
}

select:not(:checked) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works with cypress, unlike :selected.

Answer (score 0):

The css from the accepted answer also doesn't work for me. But this inline style works. Tested on Firefox 86 and Chrome 88.

```html
<select>
    <option value="1" style="display:none;" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What? display none for the first option? What will that achive?