# selectbox selection color

Tags: css, css-selectors, drop-down-menu

is there a possiblity to change the selection color in a  box? I can only find answears how to change the color on hover, but i want to change the background-color of all selected items.

i tried this selectors:

```
option[selected]{
    background-color: red;
}

option:checked{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but i had no luck

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309844/can-i-colour-backgrounds-of-selected-items-in-html-select-options-with-css-only

Comment: If there was a badge for the most removals of `css3` tags, @BoltClock would get it

Comment: @Curt: Relevant commentary - http://stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-8043622

Comment: Maybe you tested in a browser, that does not support this pseudo-selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want a custom colored/styled checkbox ,the best way for cross browser compatibility and version compatibility is designing your own checkbox button with an image. then create a hidden checkbox and trigger its properties via the custom checkbox. events like onmouseover, onmouseout, onkeydown, onkeyup, onclick etc will help u to exaxtly simulate the functions and behaviour of a regular checkbox, but fully customizable.