# Change active color in multiple select menu on the option tag

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

The selection option value is blue, however when you click on anything else on the page it becomes a faint grey. Is it possible to change either of these colors? Most importantly the faint grey for accessibility reasons.

I have tried a number of things in CSS however haven't had any luck.

```html
<label class="multiDropdown-label">Multiple Select
  <select multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: Did you try this?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36899803/1516112 It works, but I think I just a hack and not a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

@nikoskip's comment answered my question.

`select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}`

Comment: No it did not. I'm working on a solution right now for you. However, The problem is when you click an item, the highlighted color is white, which is one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress on this one... Posting current result in the meantime

```css
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: white linear-gradient(0deg, white 0%, white 100%);
  outline:none!important;
}

select[multiple]:focus option {
  background: white linear-gradient(0deg, white 0%, white 100%);
}

select[multiple] option{
   background: white linear-gradient(0deg, white 0%, white 100%);
}

/* turns off highlighting of the box completely */
select:active, select:hover, select:focus-within, select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
select {
       width: 100%;
       padding: 0;
       border: none;
       font-size: 16px;
       color: #868686;
       overflow:hidden; /* removes the scrollbar */
}
select option {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 128px;
    overflow:none;

}

[selected] { /*works in some browsers, not chrome. Working on a fix */
color:#f00; 
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```