# Angular2 multiple Select element needs to have a few selected

Tags: angular

Use Case: I have a multiple Select element with 6 colors. I need 2 of those colors selected. Thanks much. Below is my code, but something is not right?

If there is a better way of doing this, please share?

```
//view
<select name="wrColors" #wrColors [(ngModel)]="selectedColors" multiple >
  <option *ngFor="let color of allColors" [ngValue]="color">{{color.label}</option>
</select>

//component
allColors = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'red',
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'blue',
}, {
  id: 3,
  label: 'green',
}, {
  id: 4,
  label: 'yellow',
}, {
  id: 5,
  label: 'orange',
}, {
  id: 6,
  label: 'purple',
}];

selectedColors = [{
  id: 2,
  label: 'blue',
}, {
  id: 4,
  label: 'yellow',
}];

@ViewChild('wrColors') selectColorRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.updateSelectList();
}

updateSelectList() {
    let options = this.selectColorRef.nativeElement.options;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.allColors.length; i++) {

        for (let n = 0; n < this.selectedColors.length; n++) {
            if (this.selectedColors[n].Id === this.allColors[i].Id) {

                options[i].selected = true;

            }
        }

        //options[i].selected = this.selectedColors.indexOf(options[i].value) > -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could specify what problem you are facing with that code and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Everything works, but my colors are not selected.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.preselectedIds = this.selectedArr.map(obj =>{
  return obj.id;
});
//mark
this.preselectedIds = this.selectedArr.map(function (a:any) { return a.Id; });


In option tag inside ngFor,

[attr.selected]="preselectedIds.indexOf(color.id)!=-1 ? true: false"
```

Comment: that did not select anything? they all return false

Comment: The preselectedArray should have the ids of the colors that were selected by user. Inside ngfor we are checking if the id of the item is present in array and setting option selected to true and false respectively

Comment: I understand what it's trying to do, it just doesn't work? Notice that [ngValue]="color" and not [ngValue]="color.id" - but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Setting ngValue to color is correct, because you would want the entire object to send to backend or so, but I dont understand why everything is false for selected option. Is the preselected array correct?

Comment: I added this.preselected = ["1","2"] to ngOnInit()

Comment: I have edited my ans. Check if it works I created a new arr of ids because your selected array was an arr of objects.

Comment: the good news is the selected attr is equal to true - so that worked, but visually it doesn't look selected?

Comment: I did not get you. Is it that your ngmodel of select does not have both the values?

Comment: When you view HTML it shows selected="true" on the correct options. But visually they don't look selected. Which doesn't help the end user.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309844/can-i-colour-backgrounds-of-selected-items-in-html-select-options-with-css-only

Comment: perhaps it's a bug with angular2? The CSS works fine - once I click them. But it won't show any thing selected without the click... maybe cause it says, ng-pristine???