# because of 'multiple' attribute background color gets changed to grey

Tags: html, css, html-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

```
.selected_aq{
background:#47D6EB !important;
color : #fff;
}

<select id="abc" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Customer 1" class="selected_aq">Customer 1</option>
<option value="Customer 1" class="selected_aq">Customer 1</option>
</select >

 for (x=0;x<list.options.length;x++){
         if (list.options[x].selected){
             $(list.options[x]).addClass('selected_aq');
          }
```

Because of 'multiple' attribute background color gets changed to grey but only for last selected 'option'.

Comment: any one can help on this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can you please create a [mcve] so we can see what the issue is live? And also mention what browser(s) you are having the problem in.

Comment: The value `#47D6EB` is what gives grey color and not the `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS only

```css
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: #47D6EB linear-gradient(0deg, #47D6EB 0%, #47D6EB 100%);
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<select id="abc" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Customer 1" >Customer 1</option>
  <option value="Customer 2" >Customer 2</option>
  <option value="Customer 3" >Customer 3</option>
  <option value="Customer 4" >Customer 4</option>
  <option value="Customer 5" >Customer 5</option>
  <option value="Customer 6" >Customer 6</option>
</select >
```

Try to select multiple options by holding **Ctrl** button.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you are setting this grey color with `background:#47D6EB` in your class `selected_aq` and you are already setting this class to all the `options`, so it will be applied to all options.

And you don't need JavaScript to do this, you can do it with CSS [**:checked** selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: #47D6EB linear-gradient(0deg, #47D6EB 0%, #47D6EB 100%);
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: #47D6EB linear-gradient(0deg, #47D6EB 0%, #47D6EB 100%);
}
```

```html
<select id="abc" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Customer 1" >Customer 1</option>
<option value="Customer 2" >Customer 2</option>
</select>
```

For further details you can check:

**[Can I colour backgrounds of selected items in HTML select options with CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309844/can-i-colour-backgrounds-of-selected-items-in-html-select-options-with-css-only)**.