# Dropdown list highlighting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm having a dropdown list which contains the following list items,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsendmail" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlsendmail_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="test();">
    <asp:ListItem>--select--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Members">Members</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NonMembers">Non-Members</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Location">Location</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

when i choose Location, another one dropdown was bind with the values like Chennai (100), Mumbai (156),Banglore (132) etc.,

```
<tr id="tdsendmaillocation" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td>
        Location:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsendmaillocatiom" runat="server" Width="250px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="group"
            ControlToValidate="ddlsendmaillocatiom" InitialValue="0" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"><img src="images/error.png" title="Required Field" border="0" /></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to highligt just (100),(156),(132)  only  from the above list items.. in red color......

Comment: You want to restyle certain elements in a drop down list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15755873/2020893 This may serve your need.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't do that. You can't style, options in select box as usual way. There are replacement plug-ins that look like a SELECT, but are actually composed from standard HTML elements that CAN be styled like div elements.