# Changing a SELECT color based on the OPTION Selected

Tags: css, html, select

I have an HTML5 `<select>` with several `<option>` children, where each `<option>` has its own back and foreground colors. This is done via CSS and is easy enough.

What I would like to do is to maintain the `<option>` color in the `<select>` after the `<option>` has been selected. For example, let's say I have this (I'm not using CSS in the simple example below but in my real environment I am):

```
<select>
    <option style="color:red">ABC</option>
    <option style="color:blue" selected>DEF</option>
    <option style="color:green">GHI</option>
</select>
```

I would like to use CSS to somehow "transfer" the back and foreground colors of the chosen `<option>` to the `<select>` so that the `<select>` color is always  in synch with the color of the chosen `<option>`. If the user selects the third option in my example, it should appear green when selected. Choosing the first option and the text appears red. When the `<select>` is initially displayed, it should have the back and foreground colors of the initial `<option>` (blue foreground, in the example above).

I can do this through jQuery but I'd prefer to use CSS but I feel it probably can't be done.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't believe this can be done with CSS alone. Still checking, but JS or PHP will probably be your best bet.

Comment: @tom-baxter create jsFiddle with your code

Comment: As you need to detect the **change event** of `select` element, you need javascript/jquery i guess. And further Solution [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755770/change-text-color-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box)

Comment: This worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755770/change-text-color-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution I am happy with at the jsfiddle provided. The one caveat is that each `<option>` must have a background color set explicitly (it cannot inherit from the `<select>` as the `<select>` will have its background color changed as the selected `<option>` changes).

**UPDATE** Unfortunately, this "solution" only works in Chrome and Opera. So much for browser compatibility.

https://jsfiddle.net/herm0xvb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually get CLASS and COLOR from selected option element

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('select').change(function() {
      var opt =  $(this)[0].options[$(this)[0].selectedIndex];
    $(this)[0].style.backgroundColor = opt.style.backgroundColor;
    $(this)[0].className = opt.className;
  });
});
```

Comment: Why can't I just use .css() (aside from the fact that it's not working)? Doesn't .css() getthe computer style?

Comment: .css() is not working in my browser (firefox) :( dunno why....    https://jsfiddle.net/herm0xvb/2/