# Set background color of option on page load

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I am dabbiling with NodeJS Express.
On a page that is routed to from a home page I have a drop down box as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vfw0u1dz/)

The onchange event works great and was a solution I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755770/change-text-color-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box)

My goal is to have the background color from the CSS set on page load, either through an onload event or with javascript/jQuery.

I tried substituting onload in place of onclick

```
onload="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
```

which didn't work.

The option value to use when the page loads is selected from a database so it could be different every time this page is called. This doesn't need to be browser specific as I am only using Chrome

Comment: Can you give us also the backend ( NodeJS Express ) end-point code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event only works with the `body` element and elements that load in content from outside the HTML document (`img`, `iframe`, `script`, etc.) If you just add a `script` to the end of the document, it will be executed after your `select` menu has loaded.

Try putting this before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
  var dropdown = document.querySelector('select');
  dropdown.className = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].className;
</script>
```

If you have multiple `select` menus, you might want to give each an `id` attribute and use that to find them; the above code will only affect the first one on the page.