# How do I change the font color in an html table?

Tags: html, fonts, colors

How do I change the font color in an html table?

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="test">
<option value="Basic">Basic : $30.00 USD - yearly</option>
<option value="Sustaining">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</option>
<option value="Supporting">Supporting : $120.00 USD - yearly</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried

```
<span style="color: #0000ff;"> 
</span>
```

in multiple locations ... which doesn't work.

Comment: If you're trying to change the colour of the text in your select options list, thats not the table text colour that you need to change, have a look at this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755770/change-text-color-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="test" style="color: red;">
<option value="Basic">Basic : $30.00 USD - yearly</option>
<option value="Sustaining">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</option>
<option value="Supporting">Supporting : $120.00 USD - yearly</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this, if want to go old-school.

```
<font color="blue">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</font>
```

Though a more modern approach would be to use a css style:

```
<td style="color:#0000ff">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</td>
```

There are of course even more general ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
table td{
  color:#0000ff;
}

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="test">
        <option value="Basic">Basic : $30.00 USD - yearly</option>
        <option value="Sustaining">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</option>
        <option value="Supporting">Supporting : $120.00 USD - yearly</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to change specific option from the select menu
you can do it like this

```
option[value="Basic"] {
  color:red;
 }
```

or you can change them all

```
select {
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            select {
              height: 30px;
              color: #0000ff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="test">
                            <option value="Basic">Basic : $30.00 USD - yearly</option>
                            <option value="Sustaining">Sustaining : $60.00 USD - yearly</option>
                            <option value="Supporting">Supporting : $120.00 USD - yearly</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```