# How to change the color of a selected option in an html select-box?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to write css that changes the color of the selected option in a select box.
here's the select box-

```
<select id="month" name="month" autocomplete="off" class="select-box">
<option hidden selected value="0">Month</option>
    <option id="jan" value="1">Jan</option>
    <option id="feb" value="2">Feb</option>
    <option id="mar" value="3">Mar</option>
    <option id="apr" value="4">Apr</option>
    <option id="may" value="5">May</option>
    <option id="jun" value="6">Jun</option>
    <option id="jul" value="7">Jul</option>
    <option id="aug" value="8">Aug</option>
    <option id="sep" value="9">Sep</option>
    <option id="oct" value="10">Oct</option>
    <option id="nov" value="11">Nov</option>
    <option id="dec" value="12">Dec</option>
  </select>
```

i tried to use ::placeholder in css and it didnt work.
here's a picture of what i want to change:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTu0Q.png)
i want to change the "day" text.

Comment: the color text itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755770/