# using :before with option element in a drop down list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add content to the selected option in a drop down list using css, when the drop down is closed. Specifically I want the drop down to say

Sort by: Option1

when closed and when you open the drop down you then see Option 1, Option 2 etc

I found this:

[CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements)

which shows how to apply a style to the right thing, but when I try and apply :before to the option element, nothing appears, in any circumstances. That is, I cannot seem to use the

```
option:before{
 content:"before option"
}
```

as a rule to any effect.

Is this always the case for option elements? I also found that I could not wrap option text in span classes, so I can't do it that way.

Comment: try adding display: block;

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a label for the text and leave the select alone?

Comment: the design has it actually in the drop down

Comment: display:block did not seem to work for me - does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `<label>` to indicate what the `<select>` is for. You cannot use pseudo-elements on `<option>` elements because only `<option>` elements are valid within a `<select>`. The other reason you wouldn't want to do this is because pseudo-elements are typically skipped by screen readers, making the label non-accessible to a portion or the population and certain assistive technologies.

This is the proper way to associate a label such as "Sort by" with a drop down list:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RptA5/)

```
<label>
    Sort by:
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

or

```
<label for="my-select">Sort by: </label>
<select id="my-select">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
```

If you require "Sort by: " *within* the drop-down list, you should add that label within the HTML or inject it with JavaScript as CSS cannot do this. I would suggest arguing that it is not the right way to go with your designer however as you will have a bunch of redundant text and the drop-down will just look ugly.

This is how you would go about injecting the label within the drop-down using jQuery:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbjxn/)

```
$('option').each(function () {
    $(this).text("Sort by: " + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS 2.1 spec, the [`:before` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) is somewhat vaguely defined, and it says: “**Note.** This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.” Although `option` is not empty like `input`, it is still rather special. There is no clarifying definition in newer CSS specs.

In practice, browsers mostly ignore `:before` and `:after` for control elements like `select` and their children. Testing with Firefox, IE, Chrome shows that currently only Firefox implemens `option:before { content: ... }`, and only when the `select` element is “open” (either focused so that the option list is opened or has a `size` attribute with a value larger than 1).

So the approach is not feasible, and you should consider a better way to deal with the ultimate problem. Apparently, you have already found out that a visible label is to be preferred to using generated content.