# Selecting checked element in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, selector

I have an issue about selecting element inside the dropdown. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H656H/

```
<select id="razred" name="razred">
            <option hidden selected><?php echo $razred; ?></option>
            <option>1.A</option>
            <option>1.B</option>
            <option>1.C</option>
            <option>1.Č</option>
            <option>1.D</option>
            <option>1.E</option>
            <option>2.A</option>
            <option>2.B</option>
            <option>2.C</option>
            <option>2.Č</option>
            <option>2.D</option>
            <option>2.E</option>
            <option>3.A</option>
            <option>3.B</option>
            <option>3.C</option>
            <option>3.Č</option>
            <option>3.D</option>
            <option>3.E</option>
            <option>4.A</option>
            <option>4.B</option>
            <option>4.C</option>
            <option>4.Č</option>
            <option>4.D</option>
            <option>4.E</option>
        </select><br />
```

So, I want to style the  element after the user clicks it. So, only when user select an  his selection receives a styling.
I think there has to be some kind of CSS pseudo-selector for this selected  element inside dropdown.
Are there any CSS selectors for that?

Thank you all!

Comment: What element are you trying to style?

Comment: Elements inside `#razred` dropdown. Actually all with `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pseudo selector for marking select boxes the way you imagine. So the answer to your original question is No :(

But if you dont mind using a tiny bit of JavaScript then you can emulate the feature you desire. You can add a class to the select box's onchange method. Ideally this should be done from the bottom of the page inside a script tag. I m doing it inline **only as a demo**:

```
<select id="razred" name="razred" onchange='this.className="visited"'>
```

And then you could just define the custom class the way you want

```
.visited {
    color: #f00;
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /*required for webkit based browsers*/
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9K5h2/1

Answer (score 0):

Edit: removed incorrect part of answer.

The answer to your actual question regarding css:

[From a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements)

`#razred option:checked { color: red; }`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's markup.  If no value is provided, the content inside the option tag is sent with the form submission.

Comment: @cimmanon Oh, didn't know that. Thanks. Edited to only show correct part of answer :).

Answer (score 0):

The focus selector will do something that's close to what you are looking for

```
#razred:focus{
    color: blue;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H656H/2/)