# Change color of a hidden select option

Tags: html, css, html-select

I've got this:

```
  <select style="font-size: 20" id="subject" name="subject">
     <option hidden value="hello">I just want to say hello =]</option>
     <option value="quote">I'd like a quote</option>  
     <option value="general">General</option>   
  </select>
```

Works so far, but i'd like the hello option to be gray as selected (like placeholders in textareas)

if i do this:

```
  <select style="font-size: 20" id="subject" name="subject">
     <option hidden style="color:gray" value="hello">I just want to say hello =]</option>
     <option value="quote">I'd like a quote</option>  
     <option value="general">General</option>   
  </select>
```

It only changes the color of "hello" when dropped down, and not in the actual select element

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Comment: You may want to read this article:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: Was indeed a dublicate, i found this on the other submission http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/ I put in a hidden tag and it works perfectly, example: http://jsfiddle.net/udxwseew/

Comment: Put in a disabled tag before the hidden tag in my jsfiddle example, and you wont be able to select the choose option with the arrow keys either

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you mean? This will make the selected option be grey.

```
select {
    color: grey;
}
option:not(:checked) {
    color: black; /* or whatever your default style is */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6reh1ptd/

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619489/1585362

Comment: Thank you, exactly as i wanted.

Comment: Now i may just be annoying, but is there anyway to do this in-line? You know like <select style="... ? And also, if i want it to be gray only when the "hello" option is chosen, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Then you need some jQuery to apply `color:grey`. Would you like me to demonstrate?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the example, heres how i would approach it, keeping the javascript as simple as possible: http://jsfiddle.net/ntL655bh/