# Styling selected option

Tags: html, css

Pretty self explaining, I need to style the option that is selected by the user. Is this possible without javascript?

Simple example:

HTML:

```
<select multiple>
    <option class="opt1" value="">Option 1</option>
    <option class="opt2" value="">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.opt1[selected]{
    background-color: red;
}
.opt2{
    background-color: green;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6609790f/)**

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

Comment: This link would help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements

Comment: Doesn't look as though there is a :selected css tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: @Sagar Oh thanks, I've seen this post already today, but understood it the wrong way I did use `:selected` but did not try `:checked`, because I thought its only for radios/checkboxes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this .

```css
.your-select option:checked {
    background:#333;padding:20px;width:100px;border:3px solid #F00
}
```

```html
<select multiple class="your-select">
    <option class="opt1" value="">Option 1</option>
    <option class="opt2" value="">Option 2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

This article explains how to style an element by clicking on it with just css.

The idea is that you put a hidden input next to a div, and style the div based on it's neighboring input being checked.

Here's the example:

html

```
<label for="toggle-1">Do Something</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div>Control me</div>
```

css

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
   /* For mobile, it's typically better to position checkbox on top of clickable
      area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
}

/* Default State */
div {
   background: green;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: I've found my answer in the comments above, but this seems to get handy in the future, thanks!