# how to apply styles to all children of select[multiple]

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a  **select[multiple]** attribute with many options

```
<option value="85" data-select2-id="38">dolcevita</option><option value="22" data-select2-id="4">a</option><option value="6" data-select2-id="5">aa</option><option value="78" data-select2-id="6">aaaa</option>...<option value="28" data-select2-id="7">ad2</option>
```

the options are random, there can be many options

How can I apply the same css style to all those select[multiple] options?

```
<select multiple />
  <option>example1</option>
   ...
</select>
```

looked to apply styles something like this to all my options:

```
style css

 select[multiple] > option{
    background: red;
    color: black;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `select[multiple] > option`?

Comment: The CSS example does work for the select[multiple]. I would suggest getting rid of the / in your select though since the /select tag ends the select, although that doesn't affect anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187570/styling-selected-option This solved my issue thanks to bloodyKnuckles

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do, it's to disable the browsers default styles

```
.disable-select {
    user-select: none; /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
   -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
   -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
}
```

then call that class into your select tag

```
<select class="disable-select">
<option>Hello</option>
</select>
```

now you can make your styles

Comment: I'm so sorry mate, it keeps giving me the same error, 

the solution that @bloodyKnuckles published of another similar doubt was that it helped me to solve it