# HTML select option multiple - change selected items gray background when not on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I have HTML select box with multiple selection. When I select item/s and lose focus on the control - the background color of the selected items is gray and I would like to change it to some other color. I can change the background of the selected items but it only works the select box is focused and my goal is to change the color when not on focus. Here is an example in JSFiddle - notice by default the gray background:

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/w76gLox5/
```

Answer (score 0):

i updated your fiddle - this does not work in every browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/w76gLox5/1/

```
select option:checked,
select option:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

and this is also a duplicate of

[CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to change the default gray background when my select element is not on focus.

Comment: this is exactly what i posted ;) there is also a `:focus` css attribute - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/ ; check the links i posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear gradient property also with the background

`select option:checked{
  background: #1aab8e -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1aab8e 0%, #1aab8e 100%);
}`