# Show or hide div based on selected value

Tags: html, css

I have a few blocks that I want to be visible based on selected option.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
select[value="test1"] ~ #targ1 {
  display: block;
}
select[value="test2"] ~ #targ2 {
  display: block;
}
select[value="test3"] ~ #targ3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Dropdown list:
<select>
  <option value="test1">Test a</option>
  <option value="test2">Test b</option>
  <option value="test3">Test c</option>
</select>

<div id="targ1">Test 1</div>
<div id="targ2">Test 2</div>
<div id="targ3">Test 3</div>
```

I have also tried other selectors, such as `select[selected] ~ div` or
`option:focus #targ1`.

I even tried to add an `::after` pseudo element on the `select` element, but
`div`s inside the `option` tag are ignored or act weird. It seems like `select` and `option` tags have kind of their own rules which I didn't find on w3schools.

How can I show and hide the `div` elements based on the currently selected `option` using only HTML and CSS?

Edit:
Simpliest way to solve this is inline-js, but I'm looking for a no js solution.

```css
[data-value=test1] ~ #test1 {
    color: red;
}
[data-value=test2] ~ #test2 {
    color: green;
}
[data-value=test3] ~ #test3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="this.dataset.value = this.value" data-value="test1">
  <option value="test1" checked>Test a</option>
  <option value="test2">Test b</option>
  <option value="test3">Test c</option>
</select>

<div id="test1">Target 1</div>
<div id="test2">Target 2</div>
<div id="test3">Target 3</div>
```

Comment: This isn't possible without JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Woodrow Barlow actually has a good answer,
but question is more related to JS free code

Therefore the following snippet is a good example,
I actually used technique into a few pages:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            span,
            li {
                display: none;
            }

            ul {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            ul:focus li {
                display: block;
            }

            #rad1:checked ~ ul > #opt1,
            #rad1:checked ~ #targ1 {
                display: block;
            }

            #rad2:checked ~ ul > #opt2,
            #rad2:checked ~ #targ2 {
                display: block;
            }

            #rad3:checked ~ ul > #opt3,
            #rad3:checked ~ #targ3 {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="targ" value="1" hidden checked />
        <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="targ" value="2" hidden />
        <input id="rad3" type="radio" name="targ" value="3" hidden />

        <h4>Dropdown list:</h4>
        <ul tabindex="-1">
            <li id="opt1"><label for="rad1">Test 1</label></li>
            <li id="opt2"><label for="rad2">Test 2</label></li>
            <li id="opt3"><label for="rad3">Test 3</label></li>
        </ul>

        <span id="targ1">Test 1</span>
        <span id="targ2">Test 2</span>
        <span id="targ3">Test 3</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

For a regular dropdown which has only 2 states, can be used `input type="checkbox"`

---

First answer summary using url hash:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        [id*="item"] {
            display: none;
        }

        [id*="item"]:target {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="#item1">show item1</a>
            <a href="#item2">show item2</a>
            <a href="#item3">show item3</a>
        </div>

        <div tabindex="0" id="item1">item1</div>
        <div tabindex="0" id="item2">item2</div>
        <div tabindex="0" id="item3">item3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

## The bad news

In order to detect which option is currently selected with CSS, you would need to apply the `:checked` pseudo-class to the `option` element, not to the `select` element. See the question "[CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for  elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)" for more info.

```css
option:checked {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Choice 1</option>
  <option>Choice 2</option>
</select>
```

Combining that with CSS combinators ([the adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), [the general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), [the child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), and [the descendent selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)) is frustratingly ineffectual. The combinators can be combined to select any sibling or descendant, but can never select a parent or cousin... and since the HTML spec for [the `select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) says that its allowed content is "zero or more `option` or `optgroup` elements", you simply can't affect a div using the value of a select element with CSS alone.

## Using a drop-down with JavaScript

The example below monitors the select element for changes. When a change occurs, it grabs the newly-selected option element and reads the targets for that option from a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) (this is a nice convenience, because it allows you to specify the filter targets right in the HTML -- thereby keeping your model and control logic separate). Then it goes through all valid targets and either adds or removes the `.hidden` class based on whether that target is in the list provided by the data attribute.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('filter');

filter.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  var targets = option.dataset.targets.split(/(\s+)/);
  for (var target of document.getElementsByClassName('target')) {
    if (targets.indexOf(target.id) >= 0)
      target.classList.remove('hidden');
    else
      target.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.target {
  display: block;
}

.target.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="filter">
  <option data-targets="">Show no targets</option>
  <option data-targets="t1">Show target 1</option>
  <option data-targets="t2">Show target 2</option>
  <option data-targets="t1 t2">Show targets 1 and 2</option>
</select>

<div class="target hidden" id="t1">Thsi is the first target.</div>
<div class="target hidden" id="t2">This is the second target.</div>
```

## Using radio buttons without JavaScript

Unlike drop-down elements, radio buttons don't need to be nested inside a wrapping element. Because of this, you can structure your HTML so that the `div` elements are general siblings of the radio buttons, and you can use the `:checked` class to affect their visibility.

```css
.target {
  display: none;
}

#f1:checked ~ #t1 {
  display: block;
}

#f2:checked ~ #t2 {
  display: block;
}

#f3:checked ~ #t1,
#f3:checked ~ #t2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="filter" id="f0" checked><label for="f0">Show no targets</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="filter" id="f1"><label for="f1">Show target 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="filter" id="f2"><label for="f2">Show target 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="filter" id="f3"><label for="f3">Show targets 1 and 2</label>

<div class="target" id="t1">This is the first target.</div>
<div class="target" id="t2">This is the second target.</div>
```