# Can CSS3 Filter be applied to options inside <select> ?

Tags: html, css

I would like to blur the options inside a select dropdown when opened. I could blur the selected option but not the ones inside it.

```
select option {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Here's a codepen to test:

https://codepen.io/santalurr/pen/LLVWBB

Comment: No, you can't. Those form controls does not allow many CSS properties

Comment: Seems very hard (impossible ?) to custom ```option``` tags with pure CSS. You might use jQuery at least

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:hover` after the class name:

```
select option:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    filter: blur(5px);
    color: blue; /* Just checking if rule and styles are working */
}
```

Comment: Time to check first, that it works before posting...and this one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class on your blured option and do

```
<select>
    <option class="blur">tatata</option>
</select>
```

And do that in your css

```
select option.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Or just do

```
select option:checked {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked

the :checked pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 selected and  checked attributes

So, this CSS works, although styling is not possible in every browser.

You can take a look here too before click on -1...

[CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: Time to check first, that it works before posting...and this one doesn't

Comment: @Zoo

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked

the :checked pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 selected and  checked attributes


So, this CSS works, although styling is not possible in every browser.

Comment: @Poutch I don't think you should have gotten a downvote, you supplied proper sources for your code and an explanation. I would add your last comment to your answer though, that it may not always work, so that way people don't downvote it because it doesn't work in the specific environment.

Comment: Can you provide a sample where this actually works? ... And which browser(s) do I need. And FYI, I didn't down vote, just commented saying it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can't apply any styles to the HTML `<option>` with anything. You can apply some styles to the `<select>` itself, and you can entirely remove the default styles for the `<select>` using this CSS:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

You may want to use a JQuery plugin: https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/
if you want to style the `<option>`.