# Will the pseudo class :checked will select inputs with type radio or checkbox, but not <option> elements?

Tags: html, css

I came across this question in an assessment test. I know its correct for radio and checkbox. But not sure about . If it doesn't work for  then what can be done to add CSS to a selected drop-down option.
I tried this, but it doesn't work as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
select { color: red; }
option:not(:checked) { color: black; } 
</style>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: it works fine for me, tried in codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WZEMBb

Answer (score 0):

To style the currently selected option in the closed dropdown you could use:

```
    select { color: red; }
 option:not(:checked) { color: black; } /* or whatever your default style is */
```

See this: [CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: You can see this in action ar: https://jsfiddle.net/1rr9zs83 . I tried it in chrome and it works but i don't know if it works also in other browsers. Obviously it doesn't work on mobile decice.