# Is it possible to change select empty color only with css

Tags: css

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>＝select＝</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

When the user sees 「＝select＝」, I want to the color is gray.
And when selected 「1」, the color is black like this image:

[image]

```
select { color: black; }

select:empty { color: gray; }
//invalid
```

Is it possible to change color only with css? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: Thank you for your share, but  I did't mean the option. I add a photo  to help my expression... https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hcm9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function to change the `class` of the `select` element `onchange`:

```js
var myselect = document.getElementById("select1");

function colourFunction() {
  var colour = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].className;
  myselect.className = colour;
}

// Call function on load:
colourFunction();
```

```css
.color_gray {
  color: gray;
}

.color_black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="colourFunction()">
  <option disabled selected class='color_gray'>＝select＝</option>
  <option class='color_black'>1</option>
</select>
```

Note that I also used the colored `class`es on the `option` elements. But it's not mandatory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I Hope one day css can do this.