# how to change the first value of a select or placeholder?

Tags: html, css

I have a select here:

```
<select name="" id="">
 <option disabled hidden selected value="">
  default
 </option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to make the placeholder or the first value a different color so it looks like a placeholder. I have tried doing things like:

```
select option:disabled { color: red; }
select :invalid { color: red; }
select option:first-child { color: red; }
select { color: grey; } option:first-child { color: red;}
```

None of these have worked so I'm kind of stuck. I don't really want to have to use a trick like making the color transparent and putting a label on top of the select.

Comment: Maybe helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cite [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/8786880), you can't actually style it as it's rendered by the OS.

**But** fortunately, in your case, you can add the attribute `disabled` to the placeholder value: it will appear greyed out in the list and won't be selectable which will prevent your users to send the form with the placeholder value without any validation!

You can see it in action in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz7jhgtk/12/) to test it out (and also see that a bunch of rules are applied to the `option` element but none of them works).