# CSS Selector to Match All Other Elements of Same Class Except Selected One ("This")

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have multiple elements with the class `.foo`:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">Hello!</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">¡Hola!</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">Bonjour !</a>
```

When I hover over one of those, I want to be able to apply styling to all `.foo` elements, **except the one that has been hovered over**.

I suppose I'm looking for the CSS equivalent to $(this) in jQuery.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
.foo:hover::not(this) {
    color:fuchsia;
}
```

Comment: See this question and answers that followed. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8619406/8339821

Comment: Btw. SO suggest you topics based on yours. How come this are not showed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a container for your elements and you can easily do this:

```css
.box {
 display:inline-block;
}
.box:hover a {
  color:red;
}
.box a:hover {
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<a href="#" class="foo">Hello!</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">¡Hola!</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">Bonjour !</a>
</div>
```