# Change font-size based on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like the first-child in the option to have a different font-size. I'm trying various methods but it isn't happening. So far, I've got this:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2n9cfyo0/1/

I want it to appear this way by default (this is the first-child):

[image]

but change the font-size to 24px when the dropdown is chosen:

[image]

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.target option:first-child {
  font-size: 12;
}
```

```html
<select class="target">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your `.target option:first-child { font-size: 12; }` is missing the units

Comment: So basically what you want is a font size of 12px by default, and becoming 24px once an option is chosen?

Comment: There is neither jQuery nor JavaScript present in your code

Comment: Possibly more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements

Comment: @mplungjan Why would you downvote and locked my question? This is very-very different from what you have linked. I want the font-size changes in the dropdown itself. Not in another div.

Comment: @DiogoPeres What are you saying?

Comment: @AnisR. Yes. That's right.

Comment: @mplungjan No. There's nothing remotely similar to my question.

Comment: @ElaineByene then a possible way is to use an `onchange` event, that fires whenever the selected value has changed, and change the font size in the event handler.

Comment: @AnisR. Could you give an example?

Comment: @mplungjan? Hello? Why blocked my question when your suggested question isn't remotely similar to mine?

Comment: I did not downvote. I have reopened your question, but the answer is very likely "not possible" using only CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78sqgavd/1/) to achieve the same result that is required. It would require `javascript` & `jquery` to achieve the result you're expecting. Changing the dropdown from one form to another is an **Event**, and Events exists in `Jquery`, in your case, we've to use `.change()` event.

Add the below javascript code :

```
$(".target").change(function(){
   if (this.value == "2") {
     $(this).css({"font-size" : "34px"});
   }
});
```

the above code says that when you select `Option 2` from the dropdown, it would change the size of font to `34px;`, you can modify the fiddle according to your needs :)

```js
$(".target").change(function() {
  if (this.value == "2") {
    $(this).css({
      "font-size": "34px"
    });
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.target option:first-child {
  font-size: 12;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="target">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes to make it work the way I want `if (document.getElementById("dropdown_change").value != "")` and it's working well. however, When I choose `select`, it doesn't revert to the original size. Any idea?

Comment: @ElaineByene Here is my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nm10fkrc/) . If this solution worked, don't forget to up vote too :D