# Remove blue color of options when click on multiselect selection

Tags: jquery, css

I have selectbox with multiple attribute,

```
<select multiple class="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Options give a blue background color when focus on one of them (not on mouse over; on click or select an option). 
on `hover` I can change background-color. But I don't no how can I change selected item background-color.

here is my css. I test `checked, focus, active` events,

```
.test option:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.test option:checked {
  background-color: #ddd
}
.test option:focus {
  background-color: #ddd
}
.test option:active {
  background-color: #ddd
}
```

also I test `::selection` but it doesn't seems works;

```
::selection {
  background-color: red
}
```

I try to do it with jquery:

```
$('.test option').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

but click event doesn't on select event of option.

Comment: Did you try `:focus`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: @Awais Yes. And it doen't work.

Comment: @Awais No, I edit my code. This question answer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
.test option {
        background-color:red;
}
```

Or you can do following

```
select option {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't what I want. when you click on a option you see it with blue background. I wanna to change this color.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to change the highlight color (when you hover) by using CSS!

> You have few options:

1. Is to convert `select` into `ul, li` kind of select and do anything you want with this.
2. Use libraries like [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [jQuery Form Styler](https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler) . These allow you to style in much more broad and cross-browser way.

Comment: No, I don't looking for this. first of all I use multiselect, not select. second still whin you move mouse on a option you see blue color.

Comment: @MrKaaf Got it now, updated my ans have a look please

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery would be like this:

```
$('select.test option').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

`$( ".test option" ).focus(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});`