# How to show and hide a text upon selection from selectbox options without javascript

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

I need help to show different text upon selection form dropdown without javascript

i tried below code but it also use onchange event .

```html
<div>
    <select onchange="if(selectedIndex!=0)document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=options[selectedIndex].value;">
          <option value="">&lt; select an option &gt;</option>
          <option value="term 1">term 1</option>
          <option value="term 2">term 2</option>
          <option value="term 3">term 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="t"></div>
```

I need help from you to have the same functionality but without javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will not be easily possible and even possible with current css 3 and HTML 5 standards.

Actually based on pseudo selectors and elements you can do the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

The same `checked` tag applies and for `<option>` elements from `<select>`

So based on this selector you can for example hide the selected element from the `<select>` with code like in this [StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619489/5941560)

The main problem here is that based on this pseudo selector you can select only elements that are inside the `<select>` tag - this means other option tags next to the selected one.

In order to build a selector that selects the element `#t` from your example you will first need to go out for the options element level and select the `<select>` tag and look for some element after it that you can try modifying/making visible/invisible with a css. In the current selector specification you are not able to get the parent of some element. See this [stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/5941560) for any updates on that. So as of `FEB 2020` you will need again to do this with JS which makes the current effort useless.