# Change the default color of the text in the option tag when it is "SELECTED"

Tags: html, css

```css
option:checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option selected>Option1
    <option>
      <option selected>Option2
        <option>
</select>
```

In the above code, I am trying to change the default text color but the color is not changing the when the options are selected, but the color is changing when the option is not selected.

Thanks In advance!!!!

Comment: You can't really do that: the reason being that styling of `<select>` and `<option>` elements are very limited and are mostly dictated by the OS. See https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-selects-in-2019/

Comment: not sure about your HTML structure ... you might want to update the snippet . CSS selector here would be `option[selected]`

Comment: Your `html` structure for the `<select>` tag is false. Please have a look how to write it: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements)

Comment: Did you read:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-select-elements